# Use Sitefinity 11 Rest API to return Draft dynamic content

Tags: api, web-services, sitefinity

I have created a dynamic module called 'keyfacts' and using postman i successfully query the created content.

However only published items return. I would like to query items in Draft state.

Can this be done?

https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/content/keyfacts

{
    "@odata.context": "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/content/$metadata#keyfacts",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "4968ee6b-3ec5-4443-8cb9-f640c0acf197",
            "LastModified": "2018-11-15T05:41:08Z",
            "PublicationDate": "2018-11-13T12:13:26Z",
            "ExpirationDate": null,
            "DateCreated": "2018-11-13T12:13:27Z",
            "UrlName": "testkeyfact",
            "Description": "a key fact",
            "Title": "test key fact",
            "Key": "testkeyfact"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fetch draft items, you will need to first change the lifecycle status of keyfacts in the advanced settings. To do so, go to settings -> advanced settings -> WebServices -> Routes -> Frontend -> Services -> (select your web service) -> Types -> Then click on the type and change the "Lifecycle status" from Live to Master.

Click on Property mappings, click create new and then select `PersistentPropertyMapping`. Set the 'Persistent name' and 'Name' to 'ApprovalWorkflowState' and save the changes.

Now when you make a call https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/content/keyfacts?$filter=contains(ApprovalWorkflowState, 'draft'), you should only get draft items